# Token cannot be pulled by Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, token

I recorded login steps using Jmeter Recorder, and I am trying to use the authorization token dynamically so I can simulate logging users to the system.

**Here is my setup for the test**

[image]

**Here is my css-selector extractor**
[image]

**Here is my Login page HTTP-request**
[image]

The token is inside the HTML page like this

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="n8H4dNHGkK7Fpqkue5wdqq419hVAG88AgqQiOmqsIUeBZS5L3uwwQYubC4pwKgulTbXBcQx22L4luV7NxwmQXw_PWG1xCdNwvfolB-c7obs1">
```

Now each time I run, my login still failed and the `${token}` has a different token number than the one in the header response
Where did I go wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in "Match No" field, `$1$` is a template for the [Regular  Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

For the CSS Selector extractor in case of multiple matches the field allows you to:

- Pick a specific match value if you provide a positive number
- Pick a random match value if you provide `0`
- Save all matches if you provide `-1`

given you have only 1 match you can:

- leave the field blank
- use `1`
- or use `0`

More information: [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)